# Для чего нужен паттерн Factory Method

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Есть абстрактный класс-создатель `Factory` с методом-фабрикой `getProduct()` и дочерние от него.

Есть абстрактный класс-продукт `Product` и дочерние от него.

Классы-фабрики создают соответствующие им объекты классов-продуктов.

```
abstract class Factory {
    abstract function getProduct();
}
class FirstFactory extends Factory {
    public function getProduct() {
        return new FirstProduct();
    }
}

abstract class Product {
};
class FirstProduct extends Product {
}
```

В результате можно юзать такой клиентский код:

```
$factory = new FirstFactory();
$firstProduct = $factory->getProduct();
$factory = new SecondFactory();
$secondProduct = $factory->getProduct();
```

Вопрос в следующем. Зачем нужен такой паттерн? Ведь я могу в клиентском коде просто сказать:

```
$firstProduct = new FirstProduct();
$secondProduct = new SecondProduct();
```

Comment: например в коде у тебя есть метод которому нужен продукт, возможно много методов, в них ты просто берешь и вызываешь factory->getProduct(), и когда тебе надо будет заменить тип продукта с FirstProduct, на SecondProduct надо будет просто при инициализации factory, в одном месте поменять на SecondFactory, весь остальной код при этом не поменяется

Comment: То, что вы привели - это не Factory Method, а Abstract Factory. Это разные порождающие шаблоны.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а в чем принципиальная разница, кроме количества классов фабрик? :)

Comment: @Grundy в каждом методе, где нужен продукт, я должен сначала создать $factory = new FirstFactory(); И когда нужно заменить тип продукта, то я должен буду везде поменять $factory = new FirstFactory() на $factory = new SecondFactory(); Пока профита не вижу

Comment: @МаксатОрунханов, вообще фабрика должна создаваться в одном месте, иначе ты просто выбрал не тот шаблон, для своей задачи :)

Comment: @Grundy э... действительно, какая разница - метод или класс? И то, и другое из буков состоит...

Comment: @Grundy У меня нет задачи. Я изучаю паттерны, и не могу понять назначение этого паттерна. Если я могу напрямую вызвать нужный мне класс, зачем мне использовать фабрику? Какой от нее профит?

Comment: @МаксатОрунханов у вас классы слишком простые - конструкторы параметров не принимают.

Comment: @Grundy могли бы пояснить тогда в нужном контексте, как применять паттерн, и в чем его профит?

Comment: решите какой паттерн вы хотите разобрать? так как у вас в заголовке один назван, а в теле другой описан

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman в теле тоже Factory Method.

Comment: Abstract Factory - это когда в дочернем классе-фабрике генерируется группа родственных объектов

Comment: обычно метод называют `create`, а не `get` - вот это меня смутило

Answer (score 1):

**Фабричный метод** и **Абстрактная фабрика** - это **порождающие** шаблоны, их задача создать дополнительный слой (абстракции) для создания **объектов**.

Используя их вы можете описать взаимодействие не с конкретным **объектом**, а с **интефейсом** который реализует этот объект.

Вот, как могло бы выглядеть использование этого шаблона

```
Product combineProducts(Factory factoryA, Factory factoryB) {
    $productA = factoryA->getProduct();
    $productb = factoryB->getProduct();
    return $productA->combine($productB);
}
```

Подобный метод может собирать 2 объекта в один, ничего не зная об их устройстве.

Answer (score 1):

Этот паттерн необходим для динамической замены одного продукта другим. Т. е. код уже скомпилирован, но у тебя все же есть возможность выбора любого другого продукта.
 Так же он позволят сократить время на добавление другого продукта.  После добавления нового продукта нет необходимости изменять все связные с ним классы.

Так же можно добавлять новые продукты в уже в скомпилированные код и выпущенный в продакшн.